# BrO IDS unable to start after updating interface

Tags: interface, bro

I have build Bro IDS from source code. It's successfully installed

```
user@ubuntu:~$ bro -v
bro version 2.4.1
```

I am running bro in VM. My Ethernet interface in ens33 instead of eth0. After updating node.cfg to my custom interface i.e. ens33 , i am still unable to start bro.

node.cfg

```
[bro]
type=standalone
host=localhost
interface=ens33
```

When i start broctl, i see following error logs

```
Bro 2.4.1
Linux 4.4.0-96-generic


==== No reporter.log

==== stderr.log
fatal error: problem with interface eth0 (eth0: SIOCETHTOOL(ETHTOOL_GET_TS_INFO) ioctl failed: No such device)

==== stdout.log
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited

==== .cmdline
-i eth0 -U .status -p broctl -p broctl-live -p standalone -p local -p bro local.bro broctl broctl/standalone broctl/auto

==== .env_vars
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/share/broctl/scripts:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
BROPATH=/var/spool/bro/installed-scripts-do-not-touch/site::/var/spool/bro/installed-scripts-do-not-touch/auto:/usr/share/bro:/usr/share/bro/policy:/usr/share/bro/site
CLUSTER_NODE=

==== .status
TERMINATED [atexit]

==== No prof.log

==== No packet_filter.log

==== No loaded_scripts.log
```

What i can understand from logs is that broctl is unable to read the updated node.cfg,because it is using the wrong interface. Now I need to know what else changes do I need to make in order to start bro without crash?

Comment: Just a heads up, do you plainly restart or perform broctl check, install and restart or broctl deploy?

Answer (score -1):

You should edit config file in /etc/bro/node.cfg, and change eth0 to ens33